# Why my code is only working on the first object and the summs are not adding up?

Tags: python, for-loop, sum, addition

Here is my code for Roman to Integer problem
I can not understand why the for loop is only working on the first two elements.

```
class Solution(object):
def romanToInt(self, S):
    ran = {'I': 1, 'V': 5, 'X': 10, 'L': 50, 'C': 100, 'D': 500, 'M': 1000}
    sum = 0
    for i in S:
        num = ran[i]
        num2 = ran[S[S.index(i) + 1]]
        if num >= num2:
            sum = num + num2
        else:
            sum = num - num2
        return sum
```

Comment: `S.index(i)` will only return the *first* index where `i` is found.

Answer (score 3):

It's because the "return" is inside the for loop, so when the first loop ends, the program ends, to fix it just take the "return" out of your for loop.

```
def romanToInt(self, S):

    for i in S:
        .......
        .......

    return sum
```

Answer (score 0):

return will break for loop when excute put it after for loop
and sumlogic is wrong

```
    def romanToInt(S):
 ran = {'I': 1, 'V': 5, 'X': 10, 'L': 50, 'C': 100, 'D': 500, 'M': 1000}
 sum = 0
 for i in range(len(S)-1):
    num1=ran[S[i]]
    num2=ran[S[i+1]]
    if num1>=num2:
      sum=sum+num1
    else:
      sum=sum-num1
 return sum+ran[S[-1]]
```

Comment: Nicely spotted. Could you fix up the indentation on this answer, since it's not always clear which level things are at...